# Display text outside of a trace not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python, plotly.graph-objects

I am trying to display percentages outside of the bottom (dark orange) trace on my graph.

Here is my code:

```
bar2 = go.Figure()
bar2.add_trace(go.Bar(name = 'Halted Trials', 
                     x = bar2_df['Condition'],
                     y = bar2_df['Halted'],
                      text = bar2_df['Percent'],
                      texttemplate = "%{text:.2f}%<br>",
                      textposition = 'outside',
                     marker = dict(color = 'rgb(252, 141, 98)'),
                    ))
bar2.add_trace(go.Bar(name = 'Total Trials', 
                     x = bar2_df['Condition'],
                     y = bar2_df['Total'],
                     marker = dict(color = 'rgb(252, 200, 179)'),
                    ))

bar2.update_layout(barmode = 'stack',
                  yaxis_title = 'Clinical Trials',
                  width = 1000,
                  height = 1000,
                  margin = dict(l = 0, r = 0, t = 0, b = 0, pad = 0),                  
                  legend = dict(
                      orientation = 'h',
                      yanchor = 'bottom',
                      y = -.3,
                      xanchor = 'center',
                      x= .5),
                  plot_bgcolor = 'white',
                  )
```

Here is the graph generated by the above code:
[image]

I have tried setting textposition = 'outside', but setting it as both 'inside' or 'outside' displays the same result -- the text is on the inside of the trace. Is there something I'm missing?

**update:**
Their documentation explains why this is happening.

> **textposition**
> *Code*: `fig.update_traces(textposition=<VALUE>, selector=dict(type='bar'))`
> *Type*: enumerated or array of enumerateds , one of ( `"inside"` | `"outside"` | `"auto"` | `"none"` )
> *Default*: `"auto"`
> Specifies the location of the `text`. 
> *"inside"* positions `text` inside, next to the bar end (rotated and scaled if needed). 
> *"outside"* positions `text` outside, next to the bar end (scaled if needed), unless there is another bar stacked on this one, then the text gets pushed inside. 
> *"auto"* tries to position `text` inside the bar, but if the bar is too small and no bar is stacked on this one the text is moved outside.
> If *"none"*, no text appears.

**My next question** -- how can I modify the code to create my desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by referring to [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35637889/adding-annotations-to-a-bar-graph-in-plotly), creating annotations based on the individual y value of each bar.

Here is my resultant code:

```
halt_cond = pd.DataFrame()
halted_counts = halt_df.groupby('Condition').size().reset_index(name = 'Halted')
total_counts = clin_trials.groupby('Condition').size().reset_index(name = 'Total')
halt_cond = pd.merge(halted_counts, total_counts, on='Condition', how = 'outer')
halt_cond.fillna(0, inplace=True)
halt_cond['Percent'] = (halt_cond['Halted']/halt_cond['Total']).map('{:.2%}'.format)

# create the dataframe of top 10 conditions
bar2_df = halt_cond.sort_values(by = 'Total', ascending = False).head(10)

# create the list for text annotations
xi = bar2_df['Condition']
yi = bar2_df['Halted']
annoText = bar2_df['Percent']
annotationsDict = [dict(
    x = xcoord,
    y = ycoord + 20,
    text = annoText,
    showarrow = False,
) for xcoord, ycoord, annoText in zip(xi, yi, annoText)]


bar2 = go.Figure()
bar2.add_trace(go.Bar(name = 'Halted Trials', 
                     x = bar2_df['Condition'],
                     y = bar2_df['Halted'],
                     marker = dict(color = 'rgb(252, 141, 98)'),
                    ))
bar2.add_trace(go.Bar(name = 'Total Trials', 
                     x = bar2_df['Condition'],
                     y = bar2_df['Total'],
                     marker = dict(color = 'rgb(252, 200, 179)'),
                    ))

bar2.update_layout(barmode = 'stack',
                  yaxis_title = 'Clinical Trials',
                  width = 1000,
                  height = 1000,
                  margin = dict(l = 0, r = 0, t = 0, b = 0, pad = 0),
                  legend = dict(
                      orientation = 'h',
                      yanchor = 'bottom',
                      y = -.3,
                      xanchor = 'center',
                      x= .5),
                   annotations = annotationsDict,
                   plot_bgcolor = 'white'
                  )
```